# How to Force to use EMF when printing a document on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, printing

I have Xerox printer and when i print a simple text(word document) if I select Class Driver it uses XPS data type when printing, If I choose PCL or PS driver it uses RAW data type.

What I want to do is make spooler use EMF data type when printing. How can I do this?

Edit: I'm going to test some software which make edits on a EMF print spooler file.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the printer to EMF depends on the print driver for this particular printer.

The method for my own printer would be:

- Start "Devices and Printers"
- Click the printer
- Select its Properties dialog
- Go to the *Advanced* tab
- Click the button "Print Processor..."
- Choose the best NT EMF 1.00X (mine is EMF 1.008)
- Click OK and OK